# Div Before css image not cover in div

Tags: html, css

before css div background image not be cover in background means background image broken the div and go to another div. Please help me to fix this.

Please Check this codepen link:-

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wyyJKB

This is my code

```css
.learn-more {
  background: #063047;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.learn-more:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(https://wallpapers.walldevil.com/wallpapers/a78/preview/breath-
 taking-nature-online-definition-high-background.jpg);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.15;
  left: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<style>
  /* css */
</style>
<div class="section learn-more">
  <div class="inner">
    <h2 class="" style="color:#fff;">I help you for this</h2>
    <p class="" style="color:#fff;">Do you want call</p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="" style="color:#fff;">CLICK HERE</span>
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add this .learn-more{ position: relative}

Comment: Thanks @HTMLGuruz You are great :) where i am wrong ??

Comment: If you used Pseudo-classes and also you are applying position: absolute. Then you must need to used position:relative on its relevant div.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.

HTML:

```
<div class="section learn-more">
    <div class="inner">
        <h2 class="" style="color:#fff;">I help you for this</h2>
        <p class="" style="color:#fff;">Do you want call</p>
        <p>
            <a href="#">
                <span class="" style="color:#fff;">CLICK HERE</span>
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.learn-more {
    background: #063047;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    position: relative;
}

.learn-more:before {
    content: "";
    background-image: url(https://wallpapers.walldevil.com/wallpapers/a78/preview/breath-taking-nature-online-definition-high-background.jpg);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.15;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.inner h2{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.learn-more {
    background: #063047;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    position:relative;
}
```

If you positioning any div or element to Absolute. Make sure the parent element should be `positon:relative;`

Answer (score -1):

Use position: inherit; instead of position: absolute; in class .learn-more::before

```
.learn-more::before {
    content: "";
    background-image: url(https://wallpapers.walldevil.com/wallpapers/a78/preview/breath-taking-nature-online-definition-high-background.jpg);
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: inherit;
    position: inherit;
    opacity: 0.15;
    left: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```